.NET 8 app not running due to missing PresentationFramework assembly (non-reproducible)
I have a .NET 8.0.401 app which uses the following dependencies:
>dotnet list xxx.csproj package
Project 'xxx' has the following package references
   [net6.0-windows7.0]:
   Top-level Package                     Requested   Resolved
   > Costura.Fody                        5.7.0       5.7.0
   > MahApps.Metro                       2.4.10      2.4.10
   > Newtonsoft.Json                     13.0.3      13.0.3
   > NLog                                5.3.3       5.3.3
   > System.Net.Http                     4.3.4       4.3.4
   > System.Text.RegularExpressions      4.3.1       4.3.1

I'm forcing the .NET version with a global.json file:
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "8.0.401"
  }
}

When I compile and run the app in Debug or Release, it works fine. However, there's a user who gets the following error upon running the app:
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=6.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)
File name: 'PresentationFramework, Version=6.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

The user has .NET 8 installed as well and he's running Windows 11 Pro, so that should be fine.
I don't know why he's getting this error since I'm not even referencing the PresentationFramework. I'm using MahApps.Metro for the GUI though which might be related to the PresentationFramework. I did a lot of research but I couldn't figure out how to fix this issue, especially because I cannot reproduce it.
His global assembly cache output is as follows (sorry, he only provided this screenshot):

Mine on the other hand only has a version 4.0.0 of PresentationFramework:
>gacutil /u PresentationFramework
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Assembly: PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL
Unable to uninstall: assembly is required by one or more applications
Pending references:
              SCHEME: <OPAQUE>  ID: <{71F8EFBF-09AF-418D-91F1-52707CDFA274}>  DESCRIPTION : <.NET Framework Redist Setup>
Number of assemblies uninstalled = 0
Number of failures = 0

Does that matter?
My development machine's installed .NET versions are only .NET 8 and .NET 9 preview:
>dotnet --list-sdks
8.0.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
9.0.100-preview.7.24407.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

The transitive dependencies also do not include the PresentationFramework (dotnet list xxx.csproj package --include-transitive).
Adding a PresentationFramework NuGet package reference doesn't seem to make sense either.
In what way is the .NET runtime or the global assembly cache relevant for this assembly loading issue? Would I have to do some runtime tracing of loaded DLLs or listing of required DLLs for the .NET EXE, if yes, using which application(s) preferrably?
Dependencies (x64) also said that PresentationFramework is missing on my machine but my .NET app runs correctly on my machine anyway:

Fusion++ does not record anything when I launch my .NET app, so there is nothing I can work with.

Difficult to tell. According to nuget.org | MahApps.Metro  the package doesn't support any of the newer .NET versions. Also error says PresentationFramework Version=6.0.2.0 not sure here but doesn't that mean it's trying to load the .NET 6 version somehow? Maybe on your machine there is a bunch of older SKDs installed e.g .NET Framework 4.X or .NET 6 and it somehow finds a matching PresentationFramework that way. Did you recently upgrade the application? Why are you forcing it .NET version with global.json

Also maybe don't run gacutil /u as that will try to uninstall the assembly. Just use gacutil /lr PresentationFramework

@jitter: I'm forcing .NET 8 because I also have .NET 9 preview installed which I don't want to use for distribution yet, since .NET 8 is intended for production use. I updated my post that my machine only has .NET 8 and .NET 9 installed currently, not .NET 6 and the app is running fine regardless on my machine

Surprisingly, he finally managed to fix the loading issue by simply installing .NET 6. He only had .NET 7 and .NET 8 installed. For some reason that didn't work out since the app was still configured to target .NET 6:

Visual Studio also does not allow targeting a higher version currently how it seems. However, that's fine and isn't a showstopper.
